# Topological space : Exercise in "Bounded subset and sequence limits"

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits

> Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subseteq X$. Prove that the following sentences are equivalent:
>
> 1. $A$ is bounded set.
> 2. If $(x_n)$ is bounded sequence in $A$ and $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, such as $a_n \to 0$ then $(a_n)(x_n) \to 0$.

To  prove (ii) by (i)  I thought this: Let $V$ be an open  neighborhood of $0$, since $A$ is bounded there is $s > 0$ such as $A \subseteq tV$ for every $t > s$. We assume  $y \in V$ and  $y_n \in X$ such as $y_n \to y$ . Then there is $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$  such as $y_n \in V$ for every $n \geq n_0$. As  $x_n \in A$ and $A$ is bounded by $tV$ one can write $x_n = t y_n$ for every $n \geq n_0$ and $t > s > 0$.
Therefore $(a_n)(x_n) = (a_n)t(y_n) \to t \cdot 0 \cdot y = 0$.

At this point I've been stuck. How can I prove (i) by (ii)? Furthermore, is the above thought correct?
I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $X$ supposed to be a topological vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, it only mentions that is topological space..

Comment: @kaithkolesidou In that case, what does $(a_n)(x_n)$ mean? Also, if $X$ is just a topological space, the whole idea of boundedness is not necessarily sensible.

Comment: @T.Eskin the proffesor didn't give us any other clue for $X$..  It may have some mistakes the exercise. I guess that he assumes the $X$ is a top.space over $\mathbb R$ in order to make sense the above..